# Select value ordered by another value in same table without sub-query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using SQL on GBQ.

I have a table with the following columns:

| titlenum | title | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | H:A:F | 1 |
| 2 | R:V:G | 1 |
| 1 | v234 | 2 |
| 2 | B:N:E | 2 |
| 3 | R:V:G | 2 |

I wrote a query that selects for each `ID` : the **first** `title` (ordered by `titlenum`).

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN  CAST(titlenum AS INT64 ) = 1 THEN title  END)  AS first_title
FROM `table`
GROUP BY ID
```

This returns the following result:

| titlenum | title | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | H:A:F | 1 |
| 1 | v234 | 2 |

P.S : This `SELECT` query is a part of a bigger one, that selects a lot more columns.

I need to add another condition to my query:
I want to select the title with the least value for `titlenum` that also has at least one ":" in its value.

So ideally I want this result:

| titlenum | title | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | H:A:F | 1 |
| 2 | B:N:E | 2 |

I could do a sub-query, and then use the column `first_title` in the original query:

```
SELECT MIN(title) as first_title, ID      
FROM `table` 
WHERE title like '%:%'
GROUP BY ID
```

But is there a "better" way to do it? Can I use `CASE` `WHEN` instead of a sub-query? The original query is already too large and I want to avoid adding another sub-query to it.

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, one method is aggregation:

```
select (array_agg(t order by titlenum limit 1))
from `table` t 
group by id;
```

This returns the entire row.  You could just select the title if that is what you really want:

```
select id, (array_agg(t.title order by titlenum limit 1))[ordinal(1)] as title
```

[ordinal(1)].*
from `table` t
group by id;

However, based on your numbering, don't you just want filtering:

```
select t.*
from `table` t 
where titlenum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg) is used for such cases in BigQuery:

```
with `table` as (
  select 1 as titlenum, 'H:A:F' as title, 1 as id union all
  select 2, 'R:V:G', 1 union all
  select 1, 'v234', 2 union all
  select 2, 'B:N:E', 2 union all
  select 3, 'R:V:G', 2
)
select ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(titlenum, title) ORDER BY titlenum)[OFFSET(0)].*, id
from `table`
where title like '%:%'
group by id
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select as value array_agg(t order by titlenum)[offset(0)]
from `project.dataset.table` t
where regexp_contains(title, ':')
group by id
```

when applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]